# How Update works for unique values?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-update

Look at the following code,

```
Create table #test
(   
    id int primary key,
    Name varchar(100)
)

insert into #test values (1,'John')
insert into #test values (2,'Walker')
insert into #test values (3,'Bob')
insert into #test values (4,'Tailor')
insert into #test values (5,'Phlip')
insert into #test values (6,'Kevin')

-- Query 1 : 
update #test set name = 'Joney' where id = 1

-- Query 2 :
set rowcount 1  
update #test set name = 'Joney' where id = 1 
set rowcount 0
```

1. #test table have primary key & clustered index.
2. Obviously only one row will be available for an id.
3. In query 1, will the sql server look for matching rows even after it found 1 row?
4. Will query 2 really gains some performance?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In query 1, will the sql server look for matching rows even after it found 1 row?
No. It knows that it's a primary key which it will internally look into datastructure called B+ tree and figure out where that record is.

Will query 2 really gains some performance?
No. It doesn't make any difference but adds an overhead.